# How to pull data from specific HTML table via PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I am wondering how do I get information from a specific table of an HTML document? Right now, I am pulling all of the data from the entire page, but I only want the data from the table with an id of `team_batting`. How would this be accomplished? Here is my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=41270199');
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$table = $dom->getElementByID('team_batting');

$stats = $dom->getElementsByTagName("td");

for ($i = 0; $i < $stats->length; $i++) {

    $attr = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('data-stat');

    if ($attr != 'player') {
        continue;
    }

    $nodes[] = $stats->item($i)->textContent;

    foreach($nodes as $node) {
        echo $node;
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

With this I am able to pull all of the player names from the `data-stat="player"` attribute but I only want to apply this across the `team_batting` table. How would I do this?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: To get just the `td`s within the desired table, wouldn't it be `$stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");`? That is, replace `$dom` with `$table` in that line.

Comment: I tried this, it's still pulling all player names from the page.

Comment: With some testing, I found both versions actually work fine for me and only list the batters. Is the problem that you've got your output loop inside the main loop, so that it outputs one name, then two names, then three names, etc.? (i.e. by the time it's found three players, it's output 6 names, with the first player being listed three times.)

Comment: Yes that was the problem thank you!